# Is there a better way to run a repeat command in terminal?

Tags: shell, command

I need to run a repeat command with the different filename to get the header.
However, I need to run each file.

`dfits *.fit | grep MSBTITLE`

Is there any command I can run several files and show the filename and the header I need?

Comment: What's wrong with your command?

Comment: This is your first and only question here so you might not know how this works. If the answer is helpful it is always appreciated you choose to up vote. If not, it's also okay to leave a comment explaining what else is needed. *Welcome to SO!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep` does not know the filename, so you see only the matching lines, but not which file they come from originally. I would in your case write an explicit loop:

```
for file in *.fit
do
  if titleline=$(dfits $file|grep MSBTITLE)
  then
    echo $file : $titleline 
  fi
done
```

Since `dfits` already obscures the file name in its output, we store the output from grep into a variable, and if there is a match, output this line together with the file name.